# Why is asking for a list of configuration points off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Re. [What are all possible config points on vmware-toolbox-cmd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/964428/what-are-all-possible-config-points-on-vmware-toolbox-cmd)

This has been put on hold, but I don't understand why. Maybe the mod thinks I'm asking for "learning material recommendations", but I'm not. I'm asking for a list of config points, and I don't even have one that the tool has accepted yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's considered a request for "learning material reccomendations" because what you're looking for *should* be in the vendor's documentation.  In some cases, other learning materials like tutorials or 3rd party documentation might be better sources of information than the vendor's manuals.  ServerFault isn't intended to be a repository of documentation, so questions like these are considered to be off-topic.

Comment: What happens to ServerFault if basic questions are asked and they all have answers that can be referenced instead of just voting them off? Does that attract too many newbies to the site? What is the fear or negative effects of having these types of questions and answering them properly?